# Regex question to have substring match given strings

Tags: python, regex

I want regex to combine

```
".*SimpleTaskv9MoreDetails.*"
```

or

```
".*SimpleTaskv10MoreDetails.*"
```

How can I create regex to match both of them? I know that below one matches v8 and v9

```
".*SimpleTaskv[89]MoreDetails.*"
```

But if I want both v9 and v10 to be accepted? How do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Use alternatives:

```
.*SimpleTaskv(?:9|10)MoreDetails.*
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generally match your existing pattern but with *any* non-zero-length sequence of digits in the middle, you could do this:

```
.*SimpleTaskv\d+MoreDetails.*
```

Comment: I want to match only for v9 or v10. Don't want to match with old versions